# When opening APP music in background stops playing

Tags: ios, swift

The music stops playing right after open APP, I have tried, in AppDelegate:

```
 try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient, mode: .default)
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

But the music, stops playing anyway.

The only audio session that I need is for implementing the GruveoSDK, in AppDelegate I use:

```
import GruveoSDK
GruveoCallManager.setClientId("demo")
```

Comment: Have you enabled the background modes -> audio (Capabilities)?

Comment: Yes I have! @AhmadF

Comment: Well, could you post the code for playing the audio?

Comment: @AhmadF I have modified the Question. You can see the code now that I use.

Comment: Maybe Gruveo is activating a different audio session category?

Comment: How can I prove this @matt

Comment: I guess you'd need to add some code that at some later time looks to see what your current category actually is. It is a read-only property of the audio session: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616615-category so you should be able to examine it. If you find it has been changed to playback or similar, there's your problem. And indeed this would make sense, because you cannot have background sound without a playback category. They ask you to enable background audio so they would likely set the category to playback too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I fix this issue with Gruveo SDK, calling:

`GruveoCallManager.setClientId("demo")`

In my CallViewController instead of AppDelegate.